# Building an envelope object of a particular size in java?

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I have a number of point objects (n) with various coordinates.
I have an agent with coordinates.

I want to find all points within a certain distance of point a and put them into a list.

```
public class Agent {
    private Context<Object> context;
    private Geography<Object> geography;
    ...

public Agent(Context<Object> context, Geography<Object> geography) {
    this.context = context;
    this.geography = geography;
    }

    ...

public void step() {

    //gets the coordinates of the agent, calls them coord
    Context context = ContextUtils.getContext(this);
    Geography<Agent> geography = (Geography)context.getProjection("Geography");
    Geometry geom = geography.getGeometry(this);
    Coordinate coord = geom.getCoordinates()[0];

    //creates a list of called points
    List<Object> points = new ArrayList<Object>();

    //creates an envelope object and creates envelope dimensions
    Envelope envelope = new Envelope((coord.x + 0.0001, coord.y + 0.0001, coord.x - 0.001, coord.y - 0.001);

    //for all objects within the envelope, if they are of the specific class type, add them to the list
    for(Object obj: geography.getObjectsWithin(envelope, Specific.class)) {
         trees.add(tree);
    }

    System.out.println("The number of objects in the envelope is : " + trees.size());
```

My question is: when I use these dimensions (in the code above), I get 1342 objects in my envelope. This is presumably a very small envelope that should encompass at the most 200-300. Why is it making one so large?

It is possible I am not correctly creating the envelope. Does anyone know more about the details of how to specify these envelope dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instanciate your `Envelope` wrong, it is not `Envelope(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)`but `Envelope(minX, maxX, minY, maxY)`.

And in the constructor of `Envelope`, it automatically check if `minX`is really the minimum betwwen `minX`and `maxX` otherwise it will swap `minX`and `maxX`. The constructor is in fact `Envelope(x1, x2, y1, y2)`

Take a look at the `Envelope` documentation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.12/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Envelope.java)